# Is it possible to specify ApplicationIntent = ReadOnly for Azure Data Factory connecting to on-premise SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure

The goal is for Data Factory to connect to my on premise SQL Server Availability group and run a stored procedure to generate data that is then copied to Azure SQL. So far it works, but i would love to have this SP run on a secondary (ReadOnly) node.

This (reading data from secondary node via ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly) works when used in our own applications, but for some reason when i add it to connection string in Azure Data Factory it is silently ignored (SP gets executed on primary node).

Has anyone tried this with success or is it known that its not supported?

Comment: can you share your connection string ,also are using listener ?

Comment: My connection string looks like this: "connectionString": "Data Source=tcp:XXXXX-ag.mydomain;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly".

I am using database users atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Data Factory v2 allows this by going to your Linked Services within Author and Monitor:

Find the pencil icon -> In the "Factory Resources" blade find "Connections" -> "+ New" -> Add a new SQL Server on-premise connection -> "Additional connection properties" -> Property Name: applicationintent & Value: readonly

Edit: If you need to modify an existing data source you will need to recreate it and publish it.

[image: Shown Here]

Answer (score 0):

Heh, funny thing... i was wrong on, it does actually work. 
So - for reference, ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly works for AzureDataFactory SQL Server connections (links).

More expanded explanation, why i got confused:
Data factory datalinks has some non-transparent way of encrypting the credentials in the connection settings. I was playing around with the connection strings and got the impression that the safest way to make sure you changes are applied is to create a new copy of connection.